# Send additional http headers with Express.JS for all route

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple login page at route point `('/')`. All I want to do is set header when user has successful login with hard coded username and password so that he cannot access other route without logging in. I don't want to use session or token for this. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: 1) why not using express-session? 2) how about leave some cookie that will be sent with every request, and will be validated with the server?

Answer (score 3):

In Express 4.x, one can set a header with [response.append()](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.append) or [response.set()](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.set). However, this won't do you much good on any subsequent requests a user might make after having logged in because the client-side (I'm assuming a browser) most likely won't include your custom response header in it's request headers that get sent back to your server.

To set custom headers across all your routes, you can add a custom middleware function across all routes. E.g.:

```js
var setCustomHeaderFunc = function(req, res, next) {
    res.set('SpecialCustomHeader', 'super-awesome-value');
    next();
};

app.all('*', setCustomHeaderFunc);
app.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    /* your request handler code goes here */
    res.send('<html />');
});
```

Or selectively per route:

```js
var setCustomHeaderFunc = function(req, res, next) {
    res.set('SpecialCustomHeader', 'super-awesome-value');
    next();
};

app.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    /* your request handler code goes here */
    res.send('<html />');
});
app.route('/super/special').get(setCustomHeaderFunc, function(req, res) {
    /* your request handler code goes here */
    res.send('<html />');
});
```